# ODP.NET avoid conflict with existing oracle client

Tags: c#-4.0, odp.net

i am using ODP.NET 4 with instant clinet 11 in my app and I put the following Oracle related files in the same folder where my assemblies are.

- oci.dll
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll
- oraociicus11.dll
- OraOps11w.dll
- sqlnet.ora
- tnsnames.ora

So far so good. It works fine. However there is another old app on the same machine that is using Oracle 10g client. the Oracle Home is something like ...Client_1.

What i am trying to do is to use the existing tnsnames.ora resides in the ORACLE_HOME\network\Admin folder for my ODP.NET 4 app while using Oracle instant client 11g so that I don't have to keep separate tnsnames.ora.

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tnsadmin environment variable (your tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora should be in folder you specify):

[image: Windows environment variables]

Also keep in mind that I don't believe that copying the unmananged dlls is a supported deployment option (though I have seen other people do exactly that).  These days I'd recommend the managed provider:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1q50HnUh_w

Comment: Hi, b_levitt, thank you for the reply. I tried to used managed driver but then found that the managed driver does not support OracleBulkCopy class and a lot of other classes. How do people go around this?

Comment: I didn't realize it didn't support the OracleBulkCopy class.  Good to know.